# Tool to check resource load order

Tags: page-speed

Is there a tool I can show clients that will take a page's HTML and show:
a) the order in which external resources will load,
b) which resources are blocked on other resources being downloaded?

For example: JavaScript in the head blocks any images from loading further down the page and browsers can only load 6 resources at a time from a given domain/subdomain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a bunch of tools that [illustrate the waterfall](http://www.webperformancetoday.com/2010/07/09/waterfalls-101/) (the cascading chain of HTTP requests from the browser to the server):

- [gtMetrix](http://gtmetrix.com) (combines ySlow and PageSpeed)
- [pingdom tools](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/)
- http://loadimpact.com/page-analyzer
- [webpagetest](http://www.webpagetest.org/) (best in my opinion)

Also, note that your point:

> ...browsers can only load 6 resources at a time...

is not *quite* correct, while 6 is the average number of concurrent connections **to a single server** as at mid 2011 ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5751515/725163)), this number has increased since and doesn't account for domain sharding which can increase the total number of connections by around 10x.

Answer (score 2):

The *Network* and *Timeline* tabs of Chrome's developer tools show when and how long it takes to load individual page components.

Answer (score 1):

try [yslow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) extention it might be useful

Answer (score 1):

Try http://pingdom.com
and http://gtmetrix.com/ 
are best according to me